# remove strings that occur more than once next to each other - javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I've got a string like this:

```
var main_str = 'Hi I have |str| way |str||str| too |str||str||str| many breaks';
```

I need to remove any `|str|` that occur next to another `|str|`.

Wanted result:

```
var main_str = 'Hi I have |str| way |str| too |str| many breaks |str|';
```

In other words if there are many `|str|` next to each other, we remove all but one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var main_str = 'Hi I have |str| way |str||str| too |str||str||str| many breaks';
main_str = main_str.replace(/(\|str\|){2,}/g, '|str|');

console.log(main_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to do this is to `.split()` the string based on whatever delimiter you plan on using, `.filter()` for non-empty elements, and then `.join()` with the same delimiter:

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "Hi I have |str| way |str||str| too |str||str||str| many breaks";

var x = str.split("|str|").filter(function (d){
    return d.length;
}).join("|str|");

console.log(x)
// returns "Hi I have |str| way |str| too |str| many breaks |str|";
```

This allows you to avoid making a specific regular expression for each case—no escaping characters—and instead run variables through `.split()` and `.join()`.

Not sure whether or not this solution is [faster](http://jsperf.com/string-delimiting). It seems to be faster in non-Chromium browsers. I would surmise that Chrome is efficiently, because of the v8 engine, compiling a regex before running it a million times, making the regex solution faster.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/vC7QA/)

Comment: your answer is pretty good too :) but I guess the other one is easier

Comment: @user3425760 While slightly more verbose, this solution is faster.

Comment: How much slower?  Over 1M iterations yours takes 1200ms on my machine.  The other takes 700ms.

Comment: @SeanBright I made a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-delimiting). If you compile a regex beforehand and reuse it, yours could be faster (but you didn't do that in your answer). Your browser may be optimizing it, though.

Comment: Looks like Safari is the culprit, not the regex.  Could you update the statement in your answer to reflect that fact please?  Thank you.

Comment: @SeanBright No, it's Chrome's v8 engine; the regex is probably being compiled before the loop and reused. You should change your solution to precompile the regex and reuse it. But, yes, I'll remove that part.

Comment: Well the moral of the story is that everyone should be using Chrome :D

Comment: @SeanBright I don't know. It seems that sometimes regex [is slower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1145525/2476755) in Chrome too. Once again, having vendor-specific versions of ECMAScript (and the engines on which they run) is screwing us all.

Comment: FYI - I did another jsperf test which compiled the regex and it didn't seem to make a difference in the other browsers.

Comment: @SeanBright I actually only use Safari because of its console layout. I use chrome for everything else. Hopefully, Safari 8 or whatever is being released with OSX10.10 will be as fast as Apple claimed (supposedly better than Chrome). I'm dubious, though.